# Multiple Forms in One Form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I'm working in ASP.net MVC 5 project.
I have a parent form that post data to multiple tables in database.
This parent form has a sub form that goes into another web page that posts its data into another table in database, and gets back to parent form. When user gets back to main form, data that has been entered shouldn't be lost.
Is that possible? and how through AJAX?

The other sub forms are adding multiple items. The list view of both sub forms should be in the parent form, while the adding input fields should be in modal window. How to implement those too?[wireframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XeSW.png)

Comment: viewing your wire frames there are multiple solutions. But i think better is to make JSON objects per form. You can push data in Json object after validation. Same Json object can be used to draw html tables and then on submit you can post that to server as well. After posting to server you are free to decode those json objects and use according to the requirements. Ajax is only useful if you want to insert data in tables on each add process. But its looking you want to add all data after submit.

Comment: Thank you @PontusCarme very much for your thorough reply.
Yes, I want to add all data after submit

Comment: Tell me @Dixie if you understood my provided solution otherwise i can send some sample code

Comment: your answer helped me know what to look for, but if there is a sample code, I'd appreciate it :)